# Is there any way to combine these functions into one or two functions?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javaScript and am trying to make a scoreboard counter. So far, my code looks pretty messy and DRY. Is there any way to combine the home and guest score functions into one function for each?

```
 /*Scoring*/

let homeScore = 0
let guestScore = 0

const homeScoreCard = document.getElementById("home-score");
const guestScoreCard = document.getElementById("guest-score");


function increaseHomeScore(n) {
    homeScoreCard.innerHTML = homeScore += n
 }

function increaseGuestScore(n) {
    guestScoreCard.innerHTML = guestScore += n
 }

function threePoints() {
    increaseHomeScore(3);
}

function twoPoints() {
    increaseHomeScore(2);  
}

function onePoint() {
    increaseHomeScore(1);
}

function gThreePoints() {
    increaseGuestScore(3);
}

function gTwoPoints() {
    increaseGuestScore(2);
}

function gOnePoint() {
    increaseGuestScore(1);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in question so we may be able to aid you further.

Comment: I tried to answer but SO doesn't allow 3 character answers

Comment: Sorry, I thought I included the code! It should show now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function can take a parameter of how much to increase the score by:

```
function increaseHomeScore(n) {
   homeScoreCard.innerHTML = homeScore += n
}
```

Then when you want to increase the home team score, you can call the function like this:

```
increaseHomeScore(2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! Is this how it's used? /*Scoring*/

```let homeScore = 0
let guestScore = 0

const homeScoreCard = document.getElementById("home-score");
const guestScoreCard = document.getElementById("guest-score");


function increaseHomeScore(n) {
    homeScoreCard.innerHTML = homeScore += n  
 }

 function increaseGuestScore(n) {
    guestScoreCard.innerHTML = guestScore += n
 }

function threePoints() {
    increaseHomeScore(3);
}

function twoPoints() {
    increaseHomeScore(2);  
}

function onePoint() {
    increaseHomeScore(1);
}```

Comment: That could work, or you don't even need the `threePoints`, `twoPoints`, etc... functions, rather just call the `increaseHomeScore` whenever you need to change the score.

Comment: This may sound stupid but if I leave the functions out, how would I assign those certain point increments to certain buttons?

Comment: On the button click, call the `increaseHomeScore` function. Something like  `<button onClick='increaseHomeScore(2)' />`

Comment: Okay, so I have this js                                                                                              ```function increaseHomeScore(n) {
    homeScoreCard.innerHTML = homeScore += n
} ```   and this html     ```<button class="add3" onclick="increaseHomeScore(3)">+ 3 Points</button>``` and its starting with 3 each time.

Comment: My guess is that you never set it to 0 to start. In your javascript, near the beginning you can just set the `homeScoreCard.innerHTML=0;`

Comment: OMG IT WORKS! Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. I am forever grateful for people like you that don't mind helping beginners!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here's a possible solution.

```
function handleScoreChange(score, elem) {
elem.innerText+= score
}
```

Here is the function. This way you may pass the score you want to add as first argument to the function. The second argument is reference to the "team node" in your webpage.

Comment: I don't think this would work, wouldn't `score` be coerced into a string then appended?

Comment: Thank you @Liquid.s1nn3r. Would that mean I would be creating that function for both the home and guest teams separately? I'm sorry, I'm a beginner and am struggling here lol.